# How can I derive the distribution of the L2,1 norm if the ditribution of L1 norm is given?

Tags: regression, bayesian, density-function, lasso, laplace-distribution

I understand that the L1 norm promotes sparsity and is a Laplace prior in the LASSO regression framework. I am interested in how this prior changes when we apply L2,1 regularisation instead? Is it possible to visualise this new distribution if it is different at all?

The formulation is $$X=\text{argmin}(||Y-AX||_\text{fro}+||X||_{2,1})$$

Note: By L2,1 norm I mean when we apply the L2 norm along the rows first and the L1 norm along the resulting column. Y,A, and X are complex matrices. By fro I mean the frobenius norm.